# Bugged PhpStorm UI in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, phpstorm

I am facing very annoying problem in PhpStorm. Sometimes, when I open any dialog window, it does not render correctly and dialog background becomes transparent. For better understanding I attach some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

PhpStorm details:

> PhpStorm 2016.1.2
>   Build #PS-145.1616, built on May 24, 2016
>   JRE: 1.8.0_91-b14 amd64
>   JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation

Same problem occurs since `PhpStorm-141.1912` version.

Currently using Ubuntu 14.04. I don't know what additional information can help, so feel free to ask. Already tried to update PhpStorm version, updated GPU drivers (by the way is nvidia gtx970), updated java, changde java version from oracle to jdk and vice versa, but nothing fixed that problem.

My `phpstorm64.vmoptions` file is here: http://pastebin.com/zG9n2wbm

Comment: 1) Check `idea.log` for possible hints 2) Try Java version that comes with PhpStorm

Comment: So far I've found these tickets that sound very similar: 1) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-110048 2) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-131529